# How should exceptions be handled in case of wrapper class?

Tags: java, exception

Suppose we have a class Graph and another class called GraphWrapper.
Graph class has a method called returnAdjVertices.

```
public List returnAdjVertices(int vertex) {
    if (vertex < 0 || vertex >= maxVertexCount) {
        throw exception
    }
}
```

Now we have a wrapper function in GraphWrapper which would calculate degree of a vertex

```
public static int getDegree(Graph graph, int vertex) {
    if (graph == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    if (vertext < 0 || vertex >= graph.maxVertexCount) throw exception // REDUNDANT

    return graph.returnAdjVertices(vertex).size();
}
```

Now a call to find degree is checking for vertex bound condition twice.

This means we are doing a redundant check. What is the best practice recommended for exception handling in such a case ?

Comment: Throw exception always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either rethrow an exception (it will be done automatically if you don't catch it in your wrapper)

```
public static int getDegree(Graph graph, int vertex) throws VertexOutOfBoundsException {
    return graph.returnAdjVertices(vertex).size();
}
```

or catch it in your wrapper and retranslate to another

```
public static int getDegree(Graph graph, int vertex) throws WrapperException {
    int result;
    try {
        result = graph.returnAdjVertices(vertex).size();
    } catch (VertexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new WrapperException();
    }
    return result;
}
```

or even catch it and try to fix it

```
public static int getDegree(Graph graph, int vertex) {
    int result;
    try {
        result = graph.returnAdjVertices(vertex).size();
    } catch (VertexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        result = fixGraphAndReturnAdjVertices(graph, vertex);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You shouldn't do your check again, because it can be really hard to maintain.
Selection of variant is always situative.
First variant (automatic rethrow) is good when your wrapper is on the same abstraction level with wrapped object.
Second variant is good when wrapper and wrapped objects are on different abstraction levels, as an example I can propose that "FileNotFoundException" of an object working with HDD can be translated to something like "CannotLoadDataException" of an object that try to load something if it makes no sence for caller what exactly goes wrong.
Third variant is good when your wrapper can fix things :)
So it's all up to you. Hope my answer helps.

Comment: Two comments; one, the graph check for null is redundant; a null in the graph will throw a `NullPointerException` anyway. Either elide that line, or do the check and return a proper result (correct exception or expected return value). Secondly, you should catch exceptions as explicitly as possible; the catch statement here will catch all exceptions. What if `returnAdjVertices()` finds a null value? Or divides by zero? These are hidden when it should break.

Comment: @NathanielFord, `exception` here is not `Exception`, i've used it as a custom exception class. I think i should edit my answer to clarify it, tried to edit a question for it, but edit wasn't accepted by comunity :(

Answer (score 0):

As you note, the check is redundant. So you can simply drop it from the wrapper. The exception will move up the stack of calls.

I would make it clear in the documentation of both methods that an exception is thrown when the vertex is not between the accepted bounds. Or at least make it clear in the documentation of the wrapper method that it calls the wrapped method internally, and thus throws the same exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

In this *particular* case? It's redundant, and should be eliminated–at least if you'd be throwing the *same* exception, and there are no other possible side-effects in the code.

In the *general* case? It depends *entirely* on your needs, the code, etc.

One issue is that if your explicit intent is to perform the exact same check you'd need to monitor the wrapped class to ensure the guard clause hasn't changed, or extract the guard logic into a separate method that can be called independently. This is leaky encapsulation, though.

Also, I'd throw an `IllegalArgumentException` with a message instead of an NPE.